# Why is the calling assembly "System.Private.CoreLib"?

Tags: reflection, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I have a library in webassembly where I have to differentiate between calls from a library and the entry assembly. I have the entry assembly. But when trying to get the calling assembly, I get `System.Private.CoreLib`.

The call stack is fairly simple:

```
...Helpers.ContentWrapper<History>.GetModule [d:\...\Helpers\ContentWrapper.cs] Line 25     
WasmClient.Components.Defaults.History.OnAfterRenderAsync [d:\...\WasmClient\Components\Defaults\History.razor] Line 143
```

[image: current]

[image: stack:-1]

[Update]
Same with noinlining
[image: noinlining]

Comment: Does `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` fix it?

Comment: @IS4 Unfortunately, no :(